# scale nine slice image android

Tags: android, nine-patch, image-scaling

I have a an image of a text field that I want to put as the background of my text field.  I made a nine slice image so I can change the size of the image but retain the integrity of the corners.  I have this image in my drawable xhdpi and I want to use the same image in my hdpi and mdpi.  I need to do this for multiple images in my app so I do not want to have to make a nine slice image for each pixel density.  When I drag my nine slice into photo shop to change the size of the image the black lines above and to the sid of the text box are now in the image, not a pixel above/left of my image.  Is there any way that I can scale my nine slice?  Or do I have to make a nine slice for each pixel density?

Comment: ^ That is not entirely true. By using multiple densities, you can scale the "non-scaling" parts, such as the corners like the op said.

Comment: I'm using the nine slice so that I can stretch the text box the full length of the screen without affecting the corners.  The height should change based on the pixel density, right now it does not.  It uses the xhdpi on my phone that has hdpi, which shows up taller than I want it.

Comment: I guess he realized his mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule of Thumb: When you scale your images for each density, watch out for aliasing problems even when the height and width are in integer multiples.

That is: make a nine slice for each pixel density to be safe as your black dots/lines may get cut out.

Comment: True. However, you could put one in the xhdpi directory only, but be sure to have your scaling slice at least 2 pixels wide to avoid aliasing problems (xhdpi is 2 times mdpi) or 3 pixels wide if you support ldpi screens.

Comment: Don't do that. lower density phones may have much lower RAM and heap size for your app. So you may run into OOM errors when decoding a xhdpi image. It has hurt me a few times when I try to be lazy with images.

Comment: Good advice. For those lower density phones you may want to provide separate resources in ldpi. It depends how large your nine-patches are, though.

Comment: Yea. That's why I hate it when the image provider gets lazy and just send me a "retina" folder and expects it to work on all the phones. :) developers need love too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same image for all of them, just create a new folder in `res` called `drawable-nodpi`, and it'll use that same image for all densities with no scaling. That's what I do for the majority of my 9-patches if the borders are pretty thin. If you have borders intended to be thick on an xhdpi device, keep in mind they'll appear much thicker on an mdpi device if you use the same one. If that's not an issue, go for the `nodpi` approach, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling an image with Photoshop will either remove or add pixels to the image.  When it does that it will change the scale/fill guides so they are no longer 1 pixel wide and solid black.  To avoid this crop your image to remove the guides before you scale the image then add them back in.

Or you can [convert 9-patch](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html)
 images to the other resolutions using this Google 9-patch tool.